# Stop producing excess whitespace in .png files from TikZ code

Tags: latex, org-babel, images

I've been using Org src blocks like the following to generate `.png` images of `TikZ` diagrams.

```
#+name: tikz-functions
#+header: :file tikz-functions.png
#+header: :imagemagick t :iminoptions -density 800
#+header: :imoutoptions -geometry 800 -flatten
#+header: :fit yes :border 0cm
#+header: :packages '("\\usepackage{tikz}")
#+begin_src latex :results raw file :exports both :eval never-export
\begin{tikzpicture}[domain=0:4]
    \draw[very thin,color=gray] (-0.1,-1.1) grid (3.9,3.9);
    \draw[->] (-0.2,0) -- (4.2,0) node[right] {$x$};
    \draw[->] (0,-1.2) -- (0,4.2) node[above] {$f(x)$};
    \draw[color=red]    plot (\x,\x)             node[right] {$f(x) =x$};
    \draw[color=blue]   plot (\x,{sin(\x r)})    node[right] {$f(x) = \sin x$};
    \draw[color=orange] plot (\x,{0.05*exp(\x)}) node[right] {$f(x) = \frac{1}{20} \mathrm e^x$};
  \end{tikzpicture}
#+end_src
#+RESULTS: tikz-functions
```

It produces the following image:
[image]

After upgrading to Org 9.6.6, the cropping/scaling no longer seems to work, and I get the following image instead:

[image]

I can't seem to get rid of the large white background, either by removing the `domain` argument or switching to `lualatex`. Have some of the default header arguments changed, or is there some new syntax?

Comment: OK, I think I have a fix for this, but I will need to check a little
later if it's 100% the reason (as there may have been changes with the `lualatex` installation on my system): the `:packages` argument no longer works (i.e. `\usepackage{tikz}` was not getting exported to the temporary `.tex` file created by `org-babel`). Changing it to `:headers` does produce the correct file.